# SwiftUI EnvironmentObject does not redraw the current view but its parent view

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, environmentobject

I'm trying to understand how `@EnvironmentObject` affects redrawing when a property in `ObservableObject` changes.

As per Apple's doc on [EnvironmentObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/environmentobject),

> An environment object invalidates the current view whenever the observable object changes.

If the above statement is true, wouldn't the below code invalidate and recreate `ChildView` when you press the button in `ContentView`. And that should print the following output.

```
initializing parent
initializing child
// after pressing the button
initializing child
```

Contrary to my above assumption, it actually prints

```
initializing parent
initializing child
// after pressing the button
initializing parent
```

Can anyone explain why this is the case? Why is the `ParentView` being recreated even though `ParentView` is not depending on `Library`?

```
class Library: ObservableObject {
  @Published var item: Int = 0
}

struct ContentView: View {
  @StateObject var library: Library = Library()
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ParentView()
        .environmentObject(library)
      Button {
        library.item += 1
      } label: {
        Text("increment")
      }
    }
  }
}

struct ParentView: View {
  init() {
    print("initializing parent")
  }
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Text("Parent view")
      ChildView()
    }
  }
}

struct ChildView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var library: Library
  init() {
    print("initializing child")
  }
  var body: some View {
    Text("Child view")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SwiftUI View´s can be a little tricky.

> An environment object invalidates the current view whenever the observable object changes.

does not mean the object itself is recreated. It just means the body of the view gets called and the view rebuilds itself.

Remember the struct is not the `View` itself, it´s just a "description".

I´ve added some print statements to make this more clear:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var library: Library = Library()
    
    init(){
        print("initializing content")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("content body")
            ParentView()
                .environmentObject(library)
            Button {
                library.item += 1
            } label: {
                Text("increment")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ParentView: View {
    init() {
        print("initializing parent")
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let _ = print("parent body")
            Text("Parent view")
            ChildView()
            
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var library: Library
    init() {
        print("initializing child")
    }
    var body: some View {
        let _ = print("child body")
        Text("child")
    }
}
```

this initially prints:

```
initializing content
content body
initializing parent
parent body
initializing child
child body
```

and after pressing the button:

```
content body
initializing parent
child body
```

As you see the body of those `View`´s depending on `Library` get their respective body reevaluated.

The `ParentView` initializer runs because in your `ContentView` you call `ParentView()` in the body so a new struct "describing" your View is created. The `ParentView`´s view itself stays the same so its `body` var is not called.

This [WWDC 2021](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/) video about SwiftUI Views will help you better understand this.

Comment: Ah I see. That makes total sense. As for the `ContentView`'s `body`, shouldn't it only re-render the `Button` that contains `library` instead of re-rendering the whole body that contains `library`? I guess SwiftUI rerenders the view by calling into the `body` property.

Comment: @slow exactly right.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll def check out the WWDC video.

Comment: came across this post because also encountering an issue with regards to parent view. Even though the properties affected are in a sub view, the parent view containing the subview gets rebuilt. this looks like a bad behavior when using environmentobject, or bug?

Comment: @chitgoks Take a look at the video I linked. SWIFTUI is all about identity. Hard to tell what´s going on in your case.